# Programação Funcional e Transparência Referencial

Tags: javascript, programação-funcional, haskell, erlang, f#

Transparência referencial me garante que dado mesmos valores de entrada para uma função, ela sempre vai me dar um mesmo valor de retorno.

Como eu teria que fazer no caso de uma função que acessa o banco de dados que possui estado, por exemplo na hora de gravar algo no banco e retornar o id do que foi gravado?

Comment: Não dá pra ter transparência referencial numa função que grava no banco de dados. As "funções puras" são as que não causam efeitos colaterais, e gravar no banco é um efeito colateral.

Comment: Bom saber, estava procurando por uma solução tentando encontrar um pattern para isso mas já que é assim... no caso de testes então o certo é sempre simular isso com um mock para garantir sua pureza. certo?

Comment: Cara, acho melhor eu não opinar, não sou especialista em programação funcional. Postei o comentário acima com base no que eu entendo dos conceitos, mas acho melhor esperar aparecer alguém com uma resposta mais consistente.

Comment: O que você está testando? Uma função que altera o banco de dados jamais será pura, a menos que ela seja um "no-op". No máximo você pode ter uma função idempotente - que chamada uma ou várias vezes retorna o mesmo resultado e/ou produz exatamente o mesmo efeito colateral. Um `update` pode ser idempotente (ou não), mas um `insert` jamais será. Enfim, se você [edit] sua pergunta detalhando exatamente onde quer chegar, talvez possamos ajudá-lo. (P.S. tiro no escuro: por acaso você tem um teste de unidade que faz um `insert`, e quer que esse teste retorne sempre o mesmo `id` em toda execução?)

Comment: @mgibsonbr na verdade a pergunta foi a nível conceitual mesmo, para entender como funcionaria nestes casos, tanto é que eu nem especifiquei a linguagem justamente por isso. Mas o que vocês comentaram já me ajudou bastante a entender como funciona. Estou aprendendo haskell agora e venho de programação imperativa, então tudo ainda é muito novo para mim.

Comment: A "versão" pura dessa função, que mantém a transparência referencial (mas completamente inviável na prática) seria uma função que retorna um novo banco de dados, contendo o novo dado inserido, enquanto mantém o banco original intacto (ou, mais realisticamente, retorna as instruções para se alterar o banco). E o banco teria que ser retornado somente com argumento - se ele fosse criado no disco rígido, não seria mais uma função pura.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Transparência referencial é uma boa propriedade para funções que são internas ao seu programa, porque torna mais fácil de entender o que o código faz. Funções que interagem com o mundo exterior (por exemplo, com um banco de dados) não podem ter  transparência referencial.

O núcleo de Haskell é uma linguagem puramente funcional. Mas um programa puramente funcional em Haskell na realidade são apenas instruções para construir um programa, e o programa que é construído dessa forma tem efeitos colaterais. Isso é o que o tipo `IO ()` significa: instruções para construir um programa cuja execução não tem transparência referencial.

O projeto de Erlang é um bom exemplo aqui. Em Erlang, os programas são feitos de processos que trocam mensagens. A linguagem dos processos tem transparência referencial, mas a maneira com que os processos trocam mensagens não, porque quando um processo envia uma mensagem, o destinatário observa essa ação.