# Linguagem imperativa incorporando elementos funcionais

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem, programação-funcional, paradigma-de-programação, programação-imperativa

Ontem eu estava lendo uma resposta sobre as diferenças entre os [paradigmas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/86952) **funcional** e **imperativo**, e me deparei com essa afirmação:

> [Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos. O que são e quais suas principais diferenças?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13388/86952)
>
> *Hoje as linguagens novas e as que estão querendo estar atualizadas aderem cada vez mais ao paradigma funcional. Claro, não puramente, apenas de forma pragmática. Coloquei na tabela Scala e F# no funcional porque elas se vendem assim, mas são bem imperativas também, e implementam tudo de importante da orientação a objetos. Então até imperativo e funcional podem ser usados juntos, ainda que aí existe um paradigma que seja forte e o outro só auxiliar. **C# é um exemplo de linguagem imperativa que está cada dia mais funcional**, mas nunca deixará de ser predominantemente imperativa, e manterá sua orientação a objeto (mas que tem papel cada vez menos importante, desde o 2.0 isso vem caindo).*

Eu tenho zero de experiência em linguagens funcionais, então surgiu a dúvida:
Que aspectos de uma linguagem imperativa, como o C#, são funcionais?

Eu queria ver exemplos de funcionalidades do C# que estejam incorporando características do paradigma funcional, para tentar entender um pouco melhor a ideia por trás do modelo funcional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lá na resposta está mostrando que paradigmas imperativo e funcional são praticamente antagônicos, não é possível ter ambos integralmente na mesma linguagem. Que isso fique claro. É diferente da orientação a objeto, por exemplo, que é uma paradigma secundário, ou nem isso é, que pode ser adicionado à uma linguagem de um dos paradigmas principais. É possível pegar alguns elementos presentes comumente em um paradigma e associar de forma limitada ao outro.

Quando falamos em C# funcional, é só uma alusão ao paradigma e não que C# se torna funcional de verdade (pode parecer academicismo, que eu nem gosto, mas é importante conceituar certo, nem C#, nem JavaScript, ou outras que citam como funcionais são de fato, e nem estou falando das puramente funcionais porque para ser pura é bem complicado e torna a linguagem quase inviável na prática.

Vamos lá. C# sempre foi vista como uma linguagem orientada a objeto. Ela é também, mas ela sempre foi essencialmente imperativa, assim como Java, Ruby e até Smalltalk (esta em grau um pouco menor), ao contrário do que as pessoas imaginam. Quase todas linguagens tem alguma coisa de funcional bem superficialmente. Não podemos dizer que uma linguagem é funcional só porque ela tem função. Claro, isso não deixa de ser um ponto funcional da linguagem, mas a função na forma normal das linguagens imperativas são mais como procedimentos com comunicação de entrada, processamento e saída de dado, é só uma forma de [modularizar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223549/101) o código, um dos pilares da produtividade em programação (os outros são a sintaxe de alto nível e o gerenciamento automático de memória).

Nem vou falar de [recursividade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101) que existe desde o início da linguagem.

## Funções anônimas

Linguagens funcionais tem certas exigências para as funções, entre outras características. Uma delas é a função ser de [primeira classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/101) e de [alta ordem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150499/101). Isso significa que a função pode ser usada em qualquer lugar, então pode atribuir a função em si (não chamar e atribuir o resultado) pra uma variável local, de classe ou de instância, ou passar como parâmetro ou retorná-la, enfim qualquer lugar que faça sentido.

C# sempre pôde fazer isso com [*delegates*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/278767/101) com [clausuras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101), mas nas versões 2 e 3 melhorou a sintaxe ([*lambda*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181290/101)), [*delegates* prontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324158/101) e onde pode usar.

## Geradores

Em C# 2 criou-se os geradores ([*yield*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44293/101)) que possibilitaram, junto com as *lambdas* e a [inferência de tipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138134/101) ([`var`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101)), entre outras coisas, a criação do [LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182176/101) que é muito parecido com os *pipes* e *continuation* das linguagens funcionais (não tem [*currying*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21215/101) nativo na linguagem, mas é possível fazê-lo). Geradores são fundamentais em linguagens funcionais para muitos cenários porque ele é um dos mecanismos que permite o chamado *lazy evaluation*.

E ele permitiu maior facilidade para trabalhar com [assincronismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201998/101) com [corrotinas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241437/101). [Veja sobre o mecanismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101).

## Forma declarativa

Linguagens funcionais tendem a ser mais [declarativas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81854/101) (como demonstrado na resposta original). [C# pode fazer isto com LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14212/101). Embora você sempre pode fazer um pouco isto de forma limitada por convenção de codificação (sempre deu fazer por exemplo [Fluent Interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106955/101)), com a as tecnologias certas ficam mais fácil e mais poderoso. [Métodos de extensão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136913/101) ajudaram e afastaram um pouco mais da ideia de OOP.

Cada vez mais evita-se o controle de fluxo explícito por essas e outras formas.

## Pureza

Linguagens funcionais pregam muito a [pureza de funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255557/101) e a ausência de [efeitos colaterais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101). C# sempre permitiu certa [imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) ([mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103460/101)) que ajuda nisso ([`readonly`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151721/101) que agora pode ser usado em novos contextos antes proibidos). Mas isso foi sendo melhorado em cada versão.

O .NET possui o atributo [`[Pure]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas não é algo que a linguagem force.

Hoje é possível ter [imutabilidade reforçada na `struct`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/303834/101) ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318525/101)), [na referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/309784/101), além do que já existia por padrão para manter a [transparência referencial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74992/101).

## [*Pattern Matching*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137912/101)

Disponível e melhorando em cada versão desde a 7.0, vem permitindo uma forma anti OOP :) de selecionar o que fazer, simplificando código e dando mais robustez [eliminando muito *cast*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286192/101). Ele incentiva colocar foco no algoritmo de acordo com o tipo. [Exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242632/101).

## Expressões

C# tem transformando alguns [*statements*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101) por [expressões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101). Caso do `throw` e `switch`. E vem mais por aí.

## Tipagem

C# não tem [Algebric Data Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) ou Discriminated Unions, mas com [*generics*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101) é possível fazer algo próximo. Aliás, genericidade e metaprogramação podem ajudar muito alcançar os objetivos funcionais. Tem proposta para ADTs serem implementados na linguagem mesmo.

[Tupla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321968/101) não chega ser algo que remeta à linguagem funcional, mas quase todas tem essa forma de composição de dados, também em detrimento à orientação a objeto. Pelo menos é uma forma diferente de estruturar dados de um jeito mais informal. [Exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195460/101).

## Sintaxe simplificada

Isso não é um mecanismo específico e nem algo fundamental para uma linguagem ser considerada funcional, mas é comum que elas tenham sintaxes simplificadas, que permitem escrever códigos bem **expressivos** e pouco verbosa. Isso se contrapões especialmente ao Java que não permite expressar bem todo tipo de código. A filosofia do C# é escrever código curto e bem semântico, podendo abstrair melhor algumas operações, incluindo tendo [sobrecarga de operador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/341812/101) só para ficar em um exemplo. Mas nas últimas versões nota-se uma preocupação maior para ficar com um código mais "matemático" e enxuto (pesquise principalmente da 6 para frente, mas teve melhorias na 2, 3 e 4 também), sem perder suas características.

*Ranges* entraram em C# 8. É um tipo mais expressão e ajuda ser mais declarativo. Assim como o `foreach` que sempre foi mais declarativo escondendo o mecanismo bruto de varredura da coleção.

Não está entrando na linguagem, mas você vê as pessoas usando, a Microsoft escrevendo tipos mais simples, muitas vezes só com estado, sem esconder o detalhe da implementação, algo que é mais típico de linguagens funcionais.

Também há hoje um uso mais discreto de exceções. Exceção é efeito colateral por definição.

C# tem adotado algumas características parecidas com [*duck typing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252572/101) em alguns pontos.

Nada disso é essencial em funcional, mas tem uma certa cara em alguns sabores.

## Conclusão

Longe da lista estar completa em tudo o que o C# se aproxima mais do funcional, tem coisas que eu esqueci ou nem tem muita informação para eu poder *linkar*, ou ainda que é até sutil demais para constar como um item explícito.

Tem algumas coisas que não fáceis de ver como funcional, apenas que a filosofia é adotada mais em funcional, por exemplo nulidade que costuma ser evitada no funcional. O fato de C# colocar mecanismos novos que se contrapões à OO já é um indicativo.

Na minha resposta original eu queria deixar forte o afastamento de C# do mundo criado pela centralização dos objetos no código, que é um erro em grande parte dos cenários. Deixar o objeto menos importante, facilitando outras formas equilibra um pouco mais. Incentivar a [composição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/279252/101) tem muito mais a cara do funcional do que OO que incentiva agrupar e acoplar coisas (funcional induz muito mais a [coesão e baixo acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101)).

Não falei de reflexão e geração de código que não é exatamente funcional, mas que ajuda caminhar para isto. Também não falei no que está previsto do C# 9 pra frente, que pode ou não entrar, por exemplo [*records*](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/records.md).

O  [Gabriel Schade](https://gabrielschade.github.io/) tem bons artigos e palestras sobre o assunto e até um [biblioteca que ajuda o C# ser ainda mais funcional](https://gabrielschade.github.io/2017/12/14/welcome-tango.html).

Algumas coisas não expliquei mais para não ficar longo demais, e também porque cabe perguntas específicas já que nem tem material bom no SOpt ainda.

## Informações complementares

- [Posso usar class e struct ao mesmo tempo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/155448/101)
- [Para que serve o System.Linq no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125601/101)
- [O que é ortogonalidade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195461/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre "lambda" e LINQ? Como diferenciá-los em uma sentença?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79894/101)
- [O que são métodos Async?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175304/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Só um adendo. Pelo (pouco) que li a respeito, quem estuda os trade-offs das linguagens sabe que não existe linguagem perfeita, ela depende do uso que vai ser feito dela, que varia de caso para caso. É sobre trade-offs. E alguns acham que misturar paradigmas enfraquece a linguagem, porque mistura elementos contraditórios. E mesmo as linguagens que se preocuparam com a pureza do paradigma têm defeitos. Então é uma sinuca de bico.